# jQuery drag an element when mousedown event on its child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am kinda new in jquery and im facing a problem to drag an element if i click on its child element.

```
HTML
<div class="floatingPanel">
    <div class="dragger">
        Drag from here
    </div>
</div>

JQUERY 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dragger').mousedown(function () {
        $('.floatingPanel').draggable({
            opacity: 0.35
        });
    }).mouseup(function () {
        alert("mouse up");
    });
});
```

If i click on '.floatingPanel' area, It's still dragging. Where do I do wrong here?
the example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Xr/23/

**OK, Its solved, thanks to Polmonite for http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Xr/28/**

Comment: What exactly are you wanting it to do?

Comment: I want to drag .floatingPanel with from .dragger. I am sorry for being dumb to not mention it earlier.

Comment: It's ok, just want to make sure helping you with the right thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write:

```
$('.floatingPanel').draggable(...);
```

you're saying that the .floatingPanel element is to drag.
You should actually do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dragger').draggable({
        opacity: 0.35
    });
});
```

while specifying all the options of the draggable following the jQuery draggable's API: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/.

If what you wanted is to drag the .floatingPanel only through the .dragger you should write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.floatingPanel').draggable({
        opacity: 0.35,
        handle: '.dragger'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dragger').mousedown(function () {
        $('.dragger').draggable({
            opacity: 0.35
        });
    }).mouseup(function () {
        alert("mouse up");
    });
});
```

See the the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/6g6Xr/26/)

Should work